# Run debugging on device cause Xcode 6.0.1 to crash

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Yesterday i updated to the latest version of Xcode, since the update i experience a very strange glitch:

When i try to run the app on a device the Xcode start with the process and say "finish run the app on iPhone" and then the Xcode crashes.

what could cause this problem?
before the update everything worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this same issue and even trying to view the device from Window -> Devices would cause Xcode to crash. I updated the device to the latest version of iOS (8.0.2) and that seems to have fixed the problem (for this afternoon at least).

Comment: I spoke too soon. It crashes less frequently but the issue remains.